# How to make NIntegrate Quicker

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I'm plotting a Vector Plot of the Magnetic field produced by two rings of current. I am choosing to evaluate this result numerically. However, this calculation takes 8 minutes for me. How can I make this faster, if possible?

```
Show[
 VectorPlot3D[ 
  NIntegrate[{(z Cos[θ])/(Abs[z]^2 + Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + 
    Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2) + (-Cos[θ] + z Cos[θ])/(Abs[-1 + z]^2 + Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + 
    Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2), (z Sin[θ])/(Abs[z]^2 + Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + 
    Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2) + (-Sin[θ] + z Sin[θ])/(Abs[-1 + z]^2 + Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + 
    Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2), (-x Cos[θ] + Cos[θ]^2 - y Sin[θ] + Sin[θ]^2)/(Abs[-1 + z]^2 + 
    Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2) + (-x Cos[θ] + Cos[θ]^2 - y Sin[θ] + 
    Sin[θ]^2)/(Abs[z]^2 + Abs[x - Cos[θ]]^2 + 
    Abs[y - Sin[θ]]^2)^(3/2)}, 
  {θ, 0, 2 π}
  ], 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorScale -> Medium
 ], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 1}}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a little simplification 
(and using `Abs[x]^2=x^2` for real `x`)
and choosing an appropriate IntegrationMethod. 
Trapezoidal, the Gauss Methods and ClenshawCurtisRule seems to be the fastest.

All in all, this evaluates in 14 seconds on my machine:

```
calcFunction[x_?NumericQ, y_, z_] := Quiet@NIntegrate[{
    Cos[\[Theta]]*(z/(z^2 + (x - Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (y - 
              Sin[\[Theta]])^2)^(3/2) + (-1 + 
          z)/(2 + x^2 + y^2 - 2*z + z^2 - 2*x*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
           2*y*Sin[\[Theta]])^(3/2)),
    Sin[\[Theta]]*(z/(z^2 + (x - Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (y - 
              Sin[\[Theta]])^2)^(3/2) + (-1 + 
          z)/(2 + x^2 + y^2 - 2*z + z^2 - 2*x*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
           2*y*Sin[\[Theta]])^(3/2)),
    (((-1 + z)^2 + (x - Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (y - Sin[\[Theta]])^2)^(-3/
          2) + (z^2 + (x - Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (y - 
             Sin[\[Theta]])^2)^(-3/2))*(1 - x*Cos[\[Theta]] - 
       y*Sin[\[Theta]])
    }, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]
{time, result} = 
  Show[VectorPlot3D[
     calcFunction[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
     VectorPoints -> Fine, VectorScale -> Medium], 
    ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 
       0}, {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 1}}, {\[Theta], 0, 
      2 \[Pi]}]] // Timing;
time
Show[result, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]